# SQL image not retrieved using PHP

Tags: php, sql, image, odbc

I am having trouble getting an image to display when it is queried from an SQL database. When the image does display the entire image does not appear, only the top 1/10. I have looked at many example already, below is a portion of my code. The data seem to be stored in Hexadecimal, starting with 0xFF. I know that the code work because for a smaller image the entire image displays. Is there something I am missing with the data limits? Thanks.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$mime = "image/jpeg";
$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($Fileattach);
file_put_contents("imageFile.jpg", base64_encode($b64Src));
$picCode = '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
echo $picCode;
```

Comment: What is the field type for stored images?

Comment: Far as I can tell varbinary

Comment: Thad'd be too short (255 bytes). Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable`?

Comment: I am not the administrator of the data, but when I look at the properties of the column in SQL Server Management Studio the column reads Fileattach (varbinary(max),null) with a length of -1.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use an binary stream described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx